# Firebase Dynamic Links ApiException: 400: Length of DynamicLink 14793 is over the allowed limit of 7168

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Unhandled Exception: [firebase_dynamic_links/unknown] com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 400: Length of DynamicLink 14793 is over the allowed limit of 7168.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]

```
E/flutter (27743): 

E/flutter (27743): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:581:7)

E/flutter (27743): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)

E/flutter (27743): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (27743): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)

E/flutter (27743): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (27743): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseDynamicLinks.buildShortLink (package:firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_dynamic_links.dart:163:11)

E/flutter (27743): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (27743): #4      createDynamicLinkForRachnaye (package:rachnaye_project/services/firebase_dynamic_links_service.dart:34:7)


E/flutter (27743): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (27743): 

E/flutter (27743): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseDynamicLinks.buildShortLink (package:firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_dynamic_links.dart:184:7)

E/flutter (27743): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (27743): #1      createDynamicLinkForRachnaye (package:rachnaye_project/services/firebase_dynamic_links_service.dart:34:7)
```

getting issue on build short link

final ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink =
await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters);

Any body how to solve this issue?

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit: you're trying to create a dynamic link that is longer than is allowed by the API. Did you try creating the shorter link?

Comment: yeah you can say that, but I explain more in the answer for it..

Answer (score 0):

The error is getting because Sending to many Text in Social Meta Parameters

```
SocialMetaTagParameters(
            title: name + " | " + bio,
            imageUrl: Uri.parse(image),
            description: 'Check Out this Amazing Publisher - $authorname')
```

In Firebase Dynamic Links only allowed limit of 7168 but sending more than 14k Character that was the reason getting Exception for it.

bio String has Too many Text, that was the Reason getting Exception 400.